# Runge-Kutta method for a 2nd order nonlinear ODE/ CMC surface meridian

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to solve numerically the following IVP nonlinear second-order differential equation:
$$f''(x)=A\left(1+f'(x)^2\right)^{3/2}+\frac{\left(1+f'(x)^2\right)}{f(x)}$$

where $A$ is a constant and the problem has the initial conditions (IVP) $f(0)=R$ and $f'(0)=0$, where $R$ is also a constant.

I'm used to applying the RK4 method for first-order differential equations, but is it possible to solve it by the RK4 method as well? If so could someone provide me a good reference to understand this specific application for method? I also open to any other useful numerical method that can solve this IVP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had worked on this problem before and am glad to share it with you.

Recognize the slope $\phi=y'$ and main curvature $\kappa_1:$

$$ \dfrac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{\frac32}}=A +\dfrac{1}{y\sqrt{1+y'^2}} \tag1 $$

Let $y'= \tan \phi,\text{so that }\cos \phi =\dfrac{ 1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} =u \;$

$$\kappa_1= A+ \dfrac{u}{y} \tag2  $$

With proper sign

$$ \kappa_1+\kappa_2 = A = 2 H \tag3 $$

where $\kappa_2$ is second curvature perpendicular to the principal meridional direction.

It is an important surface of *constant mean curvature* ***CMC*** when internal pressure acts on a soap bubble as a *minimal surface area* of revolution for a given enclosed volume.

Btw It can be formulated using calculus of variations nicely.

Having a *constant mean curvature=H*, they are also known as  ***CMC Delaunay***  surfaces.

You can directly integrate to first order ODE. Its alternate form first degree:

$$\dfrac { \sin \phi\; d \phi}{dy}-\dfrac{u}{y} \to 
-\dfrac { du}{dy}-\dfrac{u}{y} = 2H  \tag4 $$

Integrating,

$$ u= - H y+\dfrac{c}{y}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} \tag 5 $$

$$ \boxed{\cos \phi = \dfrac{c}{y}- H y} \tag 6 $$
is the differential equation of DeLaunay surfaces. Vertical tangent at $ y=\sqrt{c/H}.$

*Characteristics of shape*:

When $ H= 0, $ it is a Catenary; when $ H=1 , $ it is a Circle.

The meridians $(x,y)$ are calculated numerically from above ODEs and plotted below using RK4 available with  `Mathematica`. Initial values $ R=1, y_0'= 0$

[image]

An interesting fact about Unduloids: If a conic rolls on a straight line then the Unduloids form as loci of their foci.

The second order RK4 is handled similar to first order, one more initial condition should be supplied.

Comment: @ Mate0us Forcelini:  Let me know after you obtain such  unduloid plots..

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Unfortunately, I just saw your solution now, and I used the RK4 directly to solve the system. This problem came for me dealing with the uplift capacity of plate anchors. I'll review what I did and see how your explanation fits on it. Best regards.

Comment: Glad it was helpful.

Comment: But am not clear how plate anchor deformation can be significant when plates are not thin compared to span between anchor bolts.

Comment: Actually, the present ODE describes the slip surface (the surface where the discontinuous velocity field occurs) that minimizes a functional form for the anchor pullout force. When I say plate anchors I refer to offshore shallow foundations.

Comment: OK.. I answered your last year's question (calc of variations) which was kept open on the site till now and am sorry to find it was deleted immediately after I replied to it a short while ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write your equation as a system of two first order equations and apply RK to that system.

$$
\begin{cases}
f' = &g \\
g' = &A(1+g^2)^{3/2} + \dfrac{1+g^2}{f}\\
\end{cases}
$$

with initial conditions $f(0) = R, g(0)=0$. If the method is appropriate to this particular problem is another matter. There seems to be a singularity near $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I just noticed that singularity, where it happens depends on the scalar $A$. Do you think is a problem related to the method employed or is the differential equation itself?

Comment: @MateusForcelini Yes, it depends on $A$ and $R$, I just took $A=1$ and $R=10$ in my experiment. The singularity is not related to the method, it prevails over different time steps and numerical methods.